# How should I improve my chesstempo tactics rating?

Tags: tactics, online-chess, beginner

I was stuck on a chesstempo tactics rating of around1482-1509 for about 2 days. I reached my current level within 3 days. I want to improve to an 1800+ rating. How can I improve?

Comment: A few days are not nearly enough time for any measurable improvement (the first few days are usually one adjusting from the site's default to one's "real" level, not actual improvement, so that doesn't count). Be patient - progress in chess takes time.

Comment: It's really straightforward. You just need to win a lot more games than you lose, and your rating will go up.

Comment: Try simply playing more games for a week or two, see what happens. It's too early to tell what your actual rating is after being roughly the same for only a couple of days.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not obsess with ratings let alone tactics rating on some website. (Specifying your rating to the last digit suggests you do.) It is just a number.

- Once you solved a problem. Chesstempo also shows you the **tactical motive** for this particular problem which is quite useful for learning. Make sure that you can recognize each motive in the solution. If not, learn about this particular motive and do more tactics of that type of motive. It is essential that you take the time to understand the problem with the solution at hand.
- Be **patient** when solving tactics. Don't go for the first good move you see. Consider all of your opponent's options.
- Do more tactics, but also mix it with playing regular games and resting time. The goal is to store those motifs subsconsciously and this can only be done by repition.

Answer (score 4):

Your question is not clear if chess tempo tactics rating refers to chess games or chess puzzles so I will include the answer for both.

Chess games:

The only way to improve your rating here is by winning games or drawing players at higher levels than you. The higher rated the players you beat are, the more points you will gain, and the higher rated the players who you lose to, the fewer points you will lose and of course visa versa. This is called the ELO rating system, here's a [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system) that further explain it if you so desire.

Chess Puzzles

Again this uses the ELO system. Each puzzle is given a difficulty rating. The higher this number, the more points you will get by correctly solving it, the fewer points you will lose by incorrectly solving it, and visa versa.

Therefore, for each one, don't expect linear growth. They are exponential, with the relative slope reducing as your rating increases.

All that being said, I can't stress enough how important it is to actually play to get better, not just for points. As someone famous said (idk who) "Don't chase a score when following excellence. Chase excellence and the scores will follow you."